# Windows Phone 8 MVVM light navigation with non string parameter

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I'm am new to the .NET/c# realm and I am trying to develop a Windows Phone 8 application.
I have several pages showing lists of Objects(`ListPage`). All of these pages will have a filter capability, using a commom `FilterPage`.

What I need is to pass an object from the `ListPage` to the `FilterPage`.
I want to use MVVM (MVVM light templates). I've managed to implement almost everything using the Messaging framework. I'm using a `FilterMessage` that takes the object to be passed in its constructor. 
The `ListPage` and the `FilterViewModel` listen to this message. The `ListPage` will navigate to the `FilterPage` and The `FilterViewModel` will take the Object from the message. 
The `ListPage` is notified correctly but the `FilterViewModel` is not notified because the `FilterViewModel` is created only after the `FilterPage` is first shown.

Is it possible to initialize the FilterViewModel by App start?
If you think that this is not the way to go please tell me why:)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by creating the `FilterViewModel` instance in the `ViewModelLocator` constructor.I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it. Hopefully someone with more experience will share with us his thoughts.

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<FilterViewModel>();

    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<FilterViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Since nobody else proposed a better solution I'm gonna mark this as the final answer. If someone has a better solution, post it and I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615841/get-navigation-data-in-view-model-windows-phone-8 pls let me know  if you can help me , without passing the object in messenger

Answer (score 1):

What I do in this scenario is I'm adding the instance you want to pass around to the other page into the Session object you have under PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.

On the other side after you complete navigation you can extract the instance, and you should remove it from the State.

Pay attention that if your application goes into the background when you have instances inside the State, WP will try to serialize them.

Comment: Yeah, it works if you do it your way.However I really wanna use MVVM Messaging, it's the perfect time\project for me to understand MVVM. Thanks any way for your answer