# Get Navigation data in View Model Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm using Mvvmlight INavigationService in the project, from view model I navigate to a view , and pass object as parameter ,how do I get either in the view model or in the code behind.

[I have implemented based on this](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/navigationservice-in-mvvm-light-v5/)

**My View model locator**

```
private static INavigationService CreateNavigationService()
    {
        var navigationService = new NavigationService();

        navigationService.Configure("topupdetails", new System.Uri("/Views/TopUpDetails.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));

        return navigationService;
    }
```

**View Model command executes**

```
private void OnTapCommand(MyModel tappedItem)
    {
        if (tappedItem._verified)
        {
        SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<INavigationService>().NavigateTo("topupdetails",tappedItem);

        }
```

**Page I navigated to**

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.Any())
        {
            var item = NavigationContext.QueryString.Values.First();

        }
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

In query string I just value like this "e-fghfdsfsd" but cant cast to my class object , Can I get the value in view model or in the code-behind which is best way to do this , with a minimum code in code-behind ?

Mvvmlight Version: Mvvmlight 5 [Laurent Mvvmlight 5 Announcement](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/10/announcing-mvvm-light-v5-for-windows-and-xamarin/)

[I have also referred this](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-mvvm-master---details-navigation-in-5-minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NavigationService to evaluate the NavigationContext:

```
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Views.NavigationService _navigationService = [..] // Get your NS instance here or create a new one.
var m = _navigationService.GetAndRemoveParameter(NavigationContext);
// Try to cast:
MyModel model = m as MyModel;
// Deny if it's not a valid object
if (model == null)
    return;
```

Comment: e.Parameter is not available for me,  e. Content is available it only contains the grid , stack panel in navigated page . I'm passing the object from a view model using mvvmlight INavigation

Comment: Thank you , this would work in any where in viewmodel  ? currently I passing the object with messenger service

Comment: It worked thank you , if I have to get Navigation Context I have to be in the pages code behind , then I should get the view model instance and pass them to selected item , so do I have any easier way of doing this , my problem is view model is same for the both pages. Now I think messenger is best way to do this ? , please let me know your thoughts

Comment: Using the messenger should be fine for this scenario. I don't know about the architecture of your app but you cannot always have one VM per page.

Comment: i have a list view page , and add item to list view page , both are plugged to single VM , Currently i implemented in the above way like your way and i get the data context as view model and pass the object from code-behind . this dataContext as MyViewModel and pass the object to viewmodel from code-behind. I don't know it have any known issues